# <%= > Tag (Response.Write shortcut) Removing Newlines

Tags: asp.net, newline

The <%=VariableName > Tag in asp.net seems to be removing newlines.
I made an example page to show this:

Code behind

```
    //code behind
    public string TestString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestString = "a" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "b";
    }
```

In site HTML

```
<%=TestString %>
```

This displays:

> a b

The desirable result is:

> a
>
> b
>   How do I make it work?
>   Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment.NewLine does not produce an HTML tag and should only be used on the server side.  On the client you use the `<br />` tag for a new line.

Comment: or warp the text with `<pre> </pre>`

Comment: Clint B, This produced the desirable results that I describes, thanks!